# How can I add an existing field to a new content type?

Tags: 7, nodes, files, media

I have a content type with name category and have title and an image under it. I want a select option with this category name while for my new content type "videos". How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at entityreference. With that you can reference entites to other entities. BTW: I wonder why you have chosen a nodetype "category" and not an taxonomy vocabulary.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an option to select existing field under the list of fields :

[image]

Comment: Changing the widget will work, I think?